# returning constant object and construction from temporary

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, g++, clang++

I've recently discovered difference between msvc and g++/clang++ compilers which is related to the behavior of RVO in case where a constant object is returned. A simple example which illustrates the difference:

```
#include <iostream>

class T
{
public:
    T() { std::cout << "T::T()\n"; }
    ~T() { std::cout << "T::~T()\n"; }
    T(const T &t) { std::cout << "T::T(const T&)\n"; }
    T(T &&t) { std::cout << "T::T(T&&)\n"; }
    T(const T &&t) { std::cout << "T::T(const T&&)\n"; }
};

const T getT()
{
    T tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    T nonconst = getT();
}
```

With optimizations enabled both examples will produce only T() and ~T() calls, which is expected due to RVO (which by the way ignores constness of returned type). But without them results differ.

clang++ or g++ with `-fno-elide-constructors` everything by the rules:

```
T::T()
T::T(T&&) // from non-const local tmp variable to temp storage (const, due to return-type)
T::~T()
T::T(const T&&) // from constant temp storage to nonconst variable
T::~T()
T::~T()
```

msvc (2013) is ignoring return-type constness:

```
T::T()
T::T(T&&) // from local non-const tmp var to non-const nonconst var
T::~T()
T::~T()
```

With slight modification:

```
const T getT()
{
    const T tmp; // here const is added
    return tmp;
}
```

clang++ or g++ with `-fno-elide-constructors`, everything as expected again:

```
T::T()
T::T(const T&&) // from const local tmp var to temp storage (const, due to return-type)
T::~T()
T::T(const T&&) // from constant temp storage to nonconst variable
T::~T()
T::~T()
```

msvc (2013):

```
T::T()
T::T(const T&&) // from local const tmp var to non-const nonconst var
T::~T()
T::~T()
```

All that explains next problem in the original version (without `const` for `tmp`): **if construction from constant temporary is prohibited like `T(const T &&t) = delete;` g++/clang++ produce error: `use of deleted function ‘T::T(const T&&)’` and msvc does not.**

So, **is that a bug in MSVC?** (it ignores return-type specification and breaks suggested semantic)

In short: msvc compiles the following code, g++/clang++ don't.

```
#include <iostream>

class T
{
public:
    T() { std::cout << "T::T()\n"; }
    ~T() { std::cout << "T::~T()\n"; }
    T(const T &t) { std::cout << "T::T(const T&)\n"; }
    T(T &&t) { std::cout << "T::T(T&&)\n"; }
    T(const T &&t) = delete;
};

const T getT()
{
    const T tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    T nonconst = getT(); // error in gcc/clang; good for msvc
}
```

Comment: I have a vague feeling that the role of qualifiers in copy-elision and considering-rvalue-references was revised after C++11 came out; perhaps there are different levels of defect reports that each compiler is adhering to?

Comment: Which version (including service pack version) of MSVC do you use? Here I use VS2013+SP5. The last code snippet fails (as expected) with error C2280: `T::T(const T &&)' : attempting to reference a deleted function`. Microsoft also lists limitations on RVO [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @HelloWorld, yes, my version is somewhat outdated.

Comment: @HelloWorld, I've installed 5th update pack. The snipped is highlighted as error, but the code builds successfully anyway (build/build solution).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `const` is a red herring here. We could simplify the example down to:

```
struct T
{
    T() = default;
    T(T &&) = delete;
};

T getT()
{
    T tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    T x = getT();
}
```

This fails to compile on gcc or clang, and I believe that failure is correct. Regardless of whether copy elision happens, we still do overload resolution on the constructor. From [class.copy]:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but not for an *exception-declaration*, and the
>   object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, or when the *expression* in a `return` statement is a (possibly
>   parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*, overload resolution
>   to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If
>   the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected
>   constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is
>   performed again, considering the object as an lvalue. *[ Note:* This two-stage overload resolution must be
>   performed regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the constructor to be called if elision
>   is not performed, and the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided. *—end note ]*

Following the rules, we perform overload resolution as if the object were an rvalue. That overload resolution finds `T(T&& )`, which is explicitly `delete`d. As that call is ill-formed, the entire expression is ill-formed.

Copy/move elision is merely an optimization. The code that it would elide has to be valid to begin with.

Comment: upvoted, validity of the copy constructor was already true for copy elision in c++98

Comment: @Barry okay, but the whole problem was about different thing: overload resolution is performed by each compiler, but in the end they are using different choices: const and non-const rvalue-constructors

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev Obviously if MSVC is deducing a non-const reference to a const object, that's a bug...

Comment: @Barry, interesting part here is that returning an object includes two stages with intermediate one of declared return-type. Which overload resolution should take place? Constructing return-type object or final destination? Because msvc checks availability of construction of final object from named local variable; and clang/gcc also checks construction from  return-type object to destination object.